# How can I handle un object via its reference groovy?

Tags: grails, reference

```
def c = Service1.search(params)
String filename = 'FILE.csv'
def lines = c.collect {
    String k = it[1]
    [k[0..10], it[0]].join(',')
} as List<String>
```

each  Item 'it'  is an object  like com.pakage1@123fgdg.. so it shows me an error that i can't get it[1], how i can get the value from this objects thank you .

Comment: toString() isn't method to get real content of object (but sometimes is). Must know what class it is (or what class derive)

Comment: 'c' is  a list of object  and the object is [data: ,error : ,status : ].. i want to get a csv files that contains some elemts from data list . data[ day1: ,query: ,day2] . so def lines = c.data.collect{String k = it[1]
        [k[0..10], it[0]].join(',')} render an error .   because c.data render refernces of objects not the value of objects

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your program if c is a map you should use `c.collect{ key, value-> }`

Answer (score 0):

it is an object . Suppose your class has a property named email.so can get value by using it.email. when you iterate over list it works like this .